# ¿como se implementa un observable en angular 5 en el propio componente?

Tags: angular, angular5

aki esta mi codigo la ruta de laravel nos devuelve todos los datos de una tabla

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
templateUrl: './main.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

archivo: Array<any>;


constructor(private _http: Http) { 


}


ngOnInit(){

const url = 'http://localhost/api/public/archivo';
conseguir(): Observable <Array<any>> {



return this._http.get(url).map((response) =>{

return response.json();

}).subscribe((data) => {

});

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes que nada

1. Como buena practica y siguiendo la Style Guide de angular, un componente no debería manejar peticiones HTTP directamente, para eso deberías usar un servicio.
2. Para el manejo de peticiones usa HttpClientModule en vez de HttpClient.
3. Si realmente necesitas hacer la petición dentro del componente (que no se recomienda para nada) te pongo un ejemplo usando HttpClient.

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-name',
   templateUrl: './my.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    apiUrl: string = 'http://localhost/api/public/archivo';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    petition() {

        // usando observables
        this._http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .subscribe(response => {
                let data = response['tu_propiedad'];
                // aqui procesas tu informacion como quieras
            }, error => {
                console.log('Algo salio mal');
            })

        // usando promesas

        this._http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let data = response['tu_propiedad'];
                // aqui procesas tu informacion como quieras
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Algo salio mal', err);
            })
    }
}
```

Ahora solo tendrías que llamar el método petition() en donde lo requieras